# How do I apply vendor prefixes to inline styles in reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, vendor-prefix

CSS properties in React are not automatically added with their vendor prefixes.

For example, with:

```
<div style={{
    transform: 'rotate(90deg)'
}}>Hello World</div>
```

In Safari, the rotation wouldn't be applied.

How do I get that accomplished?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

React does not apply vendor prefixes automatically.

In order to add vendor prefixes, name the vendor prefix as per the following pattern, and add it as a separate prop:

```
-vendor-specific-prop: 'value'
```

becomes:

```
VendorSpecificProp: 'value'
```

So, in the example in the question, it needs to become:

```
<div style={{
    transform: 'rotate(90deg)',
    WebkitTransform: 'rotate(90deg)'
}}>Hello World</div>
```

Value prefixes can't be done in this way. For example this CSS:

```
background: black;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, black, #111);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, black, #111);
```

Because objects can't have duplicate keys, this can only be done by knowing which of these the browser supports.

An alternative would be to use [Radium](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium) for the styling toolchain. One of its features is automatic vendor prefixing.

Our background example in radium looks like this:

```
var styles = {
  thing: {
    background: [
      'linear-gradient(90deg, black, #111)',

      // fallback
      'black',
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Note that the ms prefixes should be lowercase, unlike the capitalized webkit prefixes: https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

Answer (score 2):

I actually faced the same problem, and none of the react prefixing libraries out there did the job I wanted. So I built one myself:

[react-prefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-prefixer)

It's still pretty young (built it this morning), but I will be maintaining it. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Could you please create sandbox with usage examples? I try with MUI components like:

import prefix from 'react-prefixer';
const stylesFixed = prefix({
    webkitScrollbar: { width: 0, background: 'transparent' },
});
<Box sx={{ height: '200px', width: '500px', overflowY: 'scroll' }} style={stylesFixed}>...

But it doesn't work (I try to hide scrollbar in this case).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with react.js, but look at this js library from Lea Verou. It prefixes style direct in DOM.

http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/

Comment: prefixfree is awesome, just ensure to re-call window.StyleFix.process() if your page content updates (e.g. router navigation callback)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

https://github.com/cgarvis/react-vendor-prefix

to automatically vendor-prefix your style objects.