# Why can I not flexbox certain elements in ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I started out trying to style `<Link>` elements from `react-router`.

```
<Link style={{display: 'flex'}}>...</Link>
```

but it seems like it strips the `display` CSS property specifically.
Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

I get the same problems with

```
<a style={{display: 'flex', marginTop: '10px'}}>Test link</a>
```

(Result: Only `margin-top: 10px` is applied)

**EDIT:**
For future reference, as I see this page still gets some views:

I *really* tried using multiple vendor-specific `display` CSS attributes, and not just a single `flex` attribute value, so I realize now that the question is very vague...

The problem is that the ReactJS team changed the way they parse CSS attributes in inline styles, and we "all" really relied on an undocumented (internal) code of ReactJS. So this used to work:

```
<div style={{'display': ['flex', '-webkit-flex']}}>
    ...
</div>
```

But this doesn't anymore, since they updated that part of the code.

For further details see e.g. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this works for me using React 15.2.0: https://jsfiddle.net/s1mpLk26/

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <a style={{display: 'flex', marginTop: '10px'}}>Test link</a>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Maybe your version is outdated?

**EDIT:**
The issue is caused by the vendor prefixes:

```
{display: 'flex; display: -webkit-box', marginTop: '10px'}
```

The first issue with this is, that the given value for `display` doesn't work. It would rather be:

```
{display: 'flex', display: '-webkit-box', …}
```

This however also doesn't work, because of the duplicate `display` key in the object.

Apparently React doesn't support vendor prefixes for values as mention in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32100497/343045). The linked answer mentions that Radium enables you to use vendor prefixes with inline styles. The other option is to go with good ol' CSS.

Btw. the `-webkit-` prefix is usually not necessary anymore, as shown in the [Can i use table](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). However if you support IE10 or IE11 you'll probably want something like Autoprefixer handle the vendor prefixes for you, as they're somewhat complicated for flexbox (the syntax changed 2012 and the old syntax is still necessary for IEs).

Comment: Umm, it does indeed work for you (i.e. your code works). But not for my project. Of course, the code is found deeper than your example... How do I go about debugging this?

Comment: What kind of React component are you applying `style` on? Keep in mind that `style` only works by default if applied on a regular DOM component like `<a>`, `<span>` etc. E.g. if you're using something custom like `Link`, that component should forward `style` to a DOM component it renders.

Comment: I have some JSX where I just appended (inside the container element) an anchor tag (as in the example I gave in the OP), but then the `display` property is stripped. I know that the JS object that I pass to the `style` attribute in the JSX tag is properly populated. It just doesn't get rendered, somehow...

Comment: That's strange indeed. Can you check with the [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) if the `<a>` element receives the correct `style` as a prop?

Comment: Hmm, weird. Indeed in the React tab, I see that `<Link ...>` sets `style={ display: ...` (which I know will just be forwarded to an `<a>` tag by looking at the source of `react-router`), thanks for the tip.

Comment: Dies the `<a>` tag receive the style prop with `display` set? You should also be able to check that with the dev tools.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118282/discussion-between-tobias-and-amann).

Comment: Ok, I think we finally got the problem. See my last edit in the answer :).

Answer (score 4):

i made a codepen that uses react + flexbox

[codepen](http://codepen.io/lejoss/pen/RRyZBw?editors=1010)

when using flexbox you will need containers all the time, eg:

```
<div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}> ... </div>
```

Child elements can be container too, eg:

```
<div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}> 
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flex:1 }}> 
        <Link />
    </div>
 </div>
```

notice `flex:1` for flexing the child item

check this docs on flexbox 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

`display: 'flex'` is a property for a *container* which then contains the "flex items" - not for a single element as you seem to try to apply it.

Comment: You can use anchor tags "everywhere" according to the spec, and yes, I'm making a container of elements clickable basically.