# Styling with flexbox inside functional component using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox

For reference this article explains on how to style a component: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

When I do a simple statement like:

```
const cardStyle = {
        display: flex,
        justifyContent: center,
        alignItems: center,
        backgroundColor: `${bgColor}`,
        color: color,
        height: '150px',
        width: '300px'
}
```

I get the following error:

```
  Line 19:18:  'flex' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 20:25:  'center' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 21:21:  'center' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

I found this answer online but it wasn't to helpful [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567716/why-can-i-not-flexbox-certain-elements-in-reactjs)

This is my first question, so I appreciate your response. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Writing CSS code inside `jsx` is not like writing pure CSS, for instance here are some points about CSS in `js/jsx`:

- Every right value should be inside quotation mark so u should use"center" or "space-between" or "100%" ...but the exception is numbers which is equal to `${number}px`.
- Every left value should be camel cased and there is no dash .
- There is no semi-colons (;) but instead we use comma (,)

that's all I remember for now

and the answer to your question is that it should be like this:

```
const cardStyle = {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: bgColor,
    color: color,
    height: '150px',
    width: '300px'
}
```

So, we are basically using an `Object` for our inline styles in JSX.

Comment: To add to this answer, the reason this works is because when you don't put quotes around `flex`, React thinks it's a variable and not a CSS style.