# How to use prefixes for inline styles. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

For example.

```
        return {
        transform: 'rotateY(' + d.rotateY + 'rad) '
        + ' translateX(' + translateX + 'px)'
        + ' translateZ(' + d.translateZ + 'px)'
        + ' rotateY(' + d.rotateYAround + 'deg)',
        ...
```

How to use 'ms' prefix ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I apply vendor prefixes to inline styles in reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100495/how-do-i-apply-vendor-prefixes-to-inline-styles-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [React docs](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html):

> Vendor prefixes other than ms should begin with a capital letter. This is why WebkitTransition has an uppercase "W".

So your inline styles would look like this:

```js
return {
  msTransform: 'rotateY(' + d.rotateY + 'rad) ' +
    ' translateX(' + translateX + 'px)' +
    ' translateZ(' + d.translateZ + 'px)' +
    ' rotateY(' + d.rotateYAround + 'deg)',
  ...,

  transform: 'rotateY(' + d.rotateY + 'rad) ' +
    ' translateX(' + translateX + 'px)' +
    ' translateZ(' + d.translateZ + 'px)' +
    ' rotateY(' + d.rotateYAround + 'deg)',
  ...
}
```

Although I would recommend something that adds prefixes automatically. You might want to look into using a library such as styled-components rather than using inline styles.

Per the [styled-components docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics):

> The CSS rules are automatically vendor prefixed, so you don't have to think about it.